# Build path error when creating android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

When creating a new android application i get the following error messages.

1. Project 'appcompat_v7' is missing required source folder: 'gen'  appcompat_v7        Build path  Build Path Problem
2. The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/Edvin/Documents/Edvins Workspace/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar' MyFirstAndroidApp.      Build path  Build Path Problem

Im using Android 5.1.1 (API 22) and I've also installed other SDK packages that were required. When i create the project I compile and target with API 22 and the rest of the setting i leave as default. I've seen somewhat similar questions regarding this but the solutions have unfortunately not worked out for me.
Any help or thoughts is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you can then install Android Studio which is the officially supported IDE for android sdk. 
You won't have to download libraries jar and instead use the repositories in the maven servers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative :::
In project.properties file remove appcompat_v7 reference line. Then remove all the error lines that you get in some files like manifest.xml, values folder files, and may be in some java files. 
Since appcompat_v7 is not there then its all references should be deleted.
In activity files extend it to Activity.